# Linear elasticity: can "extremal" strain tensors be in the interior of the body?

Tags: elasticity

i am new to elastic theory. I have a question about linear elasticity. In each point $p$ of a body $\Omega$, the strain tensor has three eigenvalues $\lambda_1(p)\geq \lambda_2(p)\geq \lambda_3(p)$. Let $\partial\Omega$ be the boundary of $\Omega$ and $\mathring{\Omega}$ its interior. Can $\textrm{sup}_{p\in \mathring{\Omega}}(\lambda_1(p)) > \textrm{sup}_{p\in \partial\Omega}(\lambda_1(p))$ or $\textrm{inf}_{p\in \mathring{\Omega}}(\lambda_1(p)) < \textrm{inf}_{p\in \partial\Omega}(\lambda_1(p))$?
Or a slightly different question, can we leave the elastic domain in an interior point without leaving the elastic domain on the boundary?